# How to not group folders and files in the sidebar of VS Code but order everything alphabetically?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following file structure in VS Code:

```
├── 01-getting-started
│   ├── 01-quickstart.mdx
│   ├── 02-setup-prisma
│   │   ├── 01-add-to-an-existing-project.mdx
│   │   ├── 02-start-from-scratch-sql-migrations.mdx
│   │   ├── 03-start-from-scratch-prisma-migrate.mdx
│   │   └── index.mdx
│   ├── 03-tutorial.mdx
│   └── index.mdx
```

This is how the files are getting rendered in the VS Code sidebar:

[image]

There's an issue because the `02-setup-prisma` folder alphabetically comes *after* the `01-quickstart.mdx` file but because folders are displayed *before* files, the alphabetical order of sidebar items isn't retained.

Is it possible to make it so that the alphabetical order of sidebar items is retained, even though that would mix files and folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the

```
Explorer> Sort Order
```

setting. Try the `mixed` option which will sort alphabetically interleaving files and folders.